# Can't redirect to login page even if I set that in LoginURL web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

have an old ASP.NET web app running in a Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6.

I set up my web.config in this way in order to force redirection to Login.aspx:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="coocky" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="false"/>
</authentication>
```

However, when a user tries to go to another page like this:

```
http://myURL/blabla/AnotherPage.aspx
```

There's no redirection at all to Login.aspx.

Also, in web.cofing there are no exception pages like:

```
<location path="Default.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
</location>
```

I don't know what is missing in order to achieve that redirection.

Comment: What is in your main authorisation node?

Comment: There is no authorization node inside my web.config. I also have tested in other web apps hosted in the same IIS and the result is the same.

Comment: That server is a server for testng purposes and it has installed Visual Studio 2010. Could it spoil that redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an authorization node as well, in order to define who you are denying access to, e.g.:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```